# How do you dynamically set the upload target path when using an AJAX based file uploader?

Tags: php, ajax, file-upload

I'm trying to implement Valum's file uploader (improved by Ben Colon https://github.com/bencolon/file-uploader) and I'm running into a problem. Previously, my upload.php had the upload target set in accordance to certain input fields. See here:

```
//Directory where files are stored
if ($grade == '9')
{
$target = "storage/g9/";
}
elseif ($grade == '10')
{
$target = "storage/g10/";
}
elseif ($grade == '11')
{
$target = "storage/g11/";
}
elseif ($grade == '12')
{
$target = "storage/g12/";
}


$target = $target . $_POST['snumber'] . "." . $extension;    
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], $target);
```

Now, with an AJAX based file uploader it starts uploading before you even hit submit so PHP doesn't get a chance to pickup the input fields to decide what the upload path is going to be, it can only go to a predefined one. To see how the AJAX file uploader does it, view [their PHP on GitHub](https://github.com/bencolon/file-uploader/blob/master/server/php.php). How do I make it so the upload path changes depending on the user input fields?

Answer (score 0):

I believe PHP needs to know where to save the file as soon as you start uploading it. But, you can move the file once it's finished uploading, via PHP's [rename()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) function.

There's also [move_uploaded_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) (although I've never used it myself).

Comment: So are you suggesting I have a secondary temp folder? I understand PHP uploads work like this: client --> server's php temp folder --> path you set in php script. So instead of this, after PHP's default temp folder, move it to a SECOND temp folder where it's held till AJAX finished uploading and then move it again at the end of the upload script to where I want to move it?